# Sucess_url based on pk in GenericView from urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-generic-views

In my url.py I have urls like:

```
url(r'^messstellen/monatlicher_verbrauch/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/update/$',
    generic.UpdateView.as_view(
        model=MonatlicherVerbrauch,
        form_class=MonatlicherVerbrauchForm,
        success_url=reverse('messstellen:messstellen_index'),
        template_name='messstellen/monatlich_form.html',
    ),
```

now I want to let the `success_url` be something like:

```
success_url = redirect('messstellen:messtelle_detail', pk=pk)
```

where the pk schould be the same like in the regex pattern `(?P<pk>[0-9]+)`

Is there a way to do it in the url.py view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't define `success_url`, then Django will use your model's `get_absolute_url` method, which you could define as:

```
class MonatlicherVerbrauch(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('messstellen:messtelle_detail', args=[self.pk])
```

If your `get_absolute_url` points to a different url, then I don't think it is possible to set the `success_url` dynamically in the urls. You will have to override the view, and define `get_success_url`.

```
class MonatlicherVerbrauchUpdateView(UpdateView):
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('messstellen:messtelle_detail', args=[self.object.pk])

    # define these attributes in the view as well, to keep urls simple
    model=MonatlicherVerbrauch,
    form_class=MonatlicherVerbrauchForm,
    template_name='messstellen/monatlich_form.html',
```

Then use `MonatlicherVerbrauchUpdateView` in your urls instead of `UpdateView`.

```
url(r'^messstellen/monatlicher_verbrauch/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/update/$',
    MonatlicherVerbrauchUpdateView.as_view()),
```

The advantage of subclassing the generic view is that it separates the logic of your views from the urls.

Comment: I didn't knew you could define the `def get_absolute_url(self)` method via the Model. This is pretty nice. I can see that this might provoke problems with dynamicly choosen urls but it works for my case, where I create simple update views and don't want to fill my views.py with "useless" views.